# How do I change the language of all Powerpoint slides at once?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I want to change the proofing language of all my slides in a Powerpoint. I've tried setting the language via the Language Preferences menu, however this only changes it for new powerpoints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the spell-checking language on a PowerPoint presentation](http://superuser.com/questions/55034/change-the-spell-checking-language-on-a-powerpoint-presentation)

Comment: It seems that the newest version of PowerPoint is especially buggy in this respect. I have a text box where I've changed the language of all text to language A. (The default language is B.) So when I start typing within that text box, the language automatically changes to B. I thought maybe changing the default language helps (having tried everything else) but no. Now the default language is A, the language of all other text in the text box is A (and I've restarted PP) but all new text still appears as B. So my only remaining question is: is there a way to switch proofing off altogether?

Comment: Yes there is a way to turn of spell checking: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/937422/how-to-turn-off-automatic-spelling-checking-and-automatic-grammar-chec -- solved my problem!

Comment: The comment by https://superuser.com/a/1096722/474383 is actually more relevant. Just changing the keyboard languages (in Windows, not PowerPoint) will make all the newly created text boxes adhere to that language.

Comment: I changed settings but it is not working for new slides, always proofing is English :S

Comment: The **best solution**, imo, is to save the presentation as **XML** and to [replace language](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/change-spellcheck-language-globally-in-powerpoint/05b2f103-2e89-4157-b21a-31ae6faf1196) strings (e.g., "de-DE" with the desired language (e.g., "en-US"). It changes the language not just of normal slides, but also of **master slides**!

Answer (score 263, accepted):

To change the language of the **entire** PowerPoint easily, open the **View** tab and select the **Outline** view.

Now press

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all.
- **Tools** → **Language** → Choose your language to set.

Likewise while you have everything selected you can change other things like fonts, colours etc. Although of course in many case this is better done by changing the slide master, a presentation that has had many editors may have lots of 'hard' formatting set which deviates from the underlying master and needs resetting to be consistent. You can also reset individual slides to the master style, but this may result in placeholders moving as well, which may be undesirable in some situations.

### PowerPoint 2013

- **View** → **Outline** → select all slides (in a left menu) via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
- **Review** → **Language** → **Set Proofing Language...** → Choose your language to set.

As for me - PowerPoint **restart** was needed. 
Probably because I also did changed **Editing Language**:

- **Review** → **Language** → **Set Proofing Language...** → **Language Preferences** → **Choose Editing Languages**.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but after changing the language, the newly typed text is still in the previous language (the default one). Moreover, if you go to the master slides, select *the slide*, you'll notice, that the language in the language bar is still the default one, and the menu to change it is greyed out. I'm getting crazy that it haven't been solved by Microsoft for so many years.

Comment: Awesome! While not perfect, it certainly helps. I agree with @Endrju, why isn't this fixed yet?!

Comment: For the record, in Office 2013, the Language menu is in the Review pane (Set Proofing Language)

Comment: Powerpoint is just shockingly bad isn't it? I actually miss using open office when I have issues like this. I'll be back to open office as soon as they support saving to a video.

Comment: @Endrju You have to change language for PowerPoint in the Windows taskbar to make newly type text be in the new language. See details in [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/1096722/348544). It annoyed me a lot for such long time...

Comment: As compared to a solution with VBA that uses recursion, this is of much lower quality. It is very frequent to have text boxes and other shapes added which would not be changed by this solution.

Comment: @Endrju [Review] > [Language] > [Set Proofing Language...], click on your language and click on [Default..]

Comment: As a further note, this worked for me however SmartArt (i.e. flowcharts etc) did not change language. These can be changed by clicking on the containing box for the entire SmartArt and changing the language using the option in the bottom right of the PowerPoint window

Comment: This **will not** work for tables, text in graphic shapes and actually anything that contains editable text, but for any reason does not appear in outline view. I have a presentation where 95% of a content is such stuff and with your (otherwise great) solution I managed to change language of title and "thank you" slides. Pretty much bad as for "global" solution. Thank you, Microsoft morons, for giving us another useless piece of IT shit! :(

Comment: This does only work for existing slides. My PowerPoint just won't forget English as its spell check language, no matter what I do. As soon as I add a new slide, the new slide will have English set as its spell check language again. This *must* be a bug.

Comment: Main limitation of this is that if someone in their infinite wisdom created custom text box instead of using proper Title+Content layouts, this just won't work.

Comment: The outline is now in the proper language, but the slides still show German when I click on text in the text boxes, and still suggest German language words when you click on words with red squiggly underlining.

Comment: Does not work for me as soon as I select multiple slides or even multiple elements on a slide I'm not able to select the language anymore. Maybe due to a very broken master slide, I don't know

Comment: It's absolutely CRAZY that this shit piece of software will not let me once and for ever switch the language used in a presentation deck for good. Yes, you can select all and change it - but every new slide again is presented with the wrong language set...

Comment: As of the latest Office (Version 2011, part of Microsoft 365) the Outline trick doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Nearly 2021 and the issue described by @Endrju still remains. I hate office

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL annoying, isn't it? Especially that development of this function doesn't seem to be a rocket science... Cheers!

Answer (score 38):

Using **Powerpoint 2010** I opened the Outline menu -

[image: outline tab]

Selected all text (Ctrl+A), opened the language menu and set my proofing language

[image: language option]

And it worked!

The language menu is located on the Review ribbon tab (after the Slide Show tab and not visible on the screenshot).

Comment: Only works for a single slide

Comment: This works for basic slide layouts. It will not change the language for text inside text boxes or nested within other shapes.

Comment: Works on Office 2007 too.

Comment: Worked on Office Mac too.

Answer (score 35):

I improved upon [Inigo's answer](https://superuser.com/a/629843/200425) to provide a recursive version that changes all items to the desired language.

This version will recursively investigate each shape that is a group type. Some experimentation suggests that `msoGroup` and `msoSmartArt` are the group types - feel free to add to that list if you find other types of shapes that can hold text objects.

```vb
Sub ChangeProofingLanguageToEnglish()
    Dim j As Long, k As Long
    Dim languageID As MsoLanguageID

    'Set this to your preferred language
    languageID = msoLanguageIDEnglishUK

    For j = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        For k = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes.Count
            ChangeAllSubShapes ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes(k), _
              languageID
        Next k
    Next j
End Sub


Sub ChangeAllSubShapes(targetShape As shape, languageID As MsoLanguageID)
    Dim i As Long

    If targetShape.HasTextFrame Then
        targetShape.TextFrame.TextRange.languageID = languageID
    End If

    Select Case targetShape.Type
        Case msoGroup, msoSmartArt
            For i = 1 To targetShape.GroupItems.Count
                ChangeAllSubShapes targetShape.GroupItems.Item(i), languageID
            Next i
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: When running this in PowerPoint 16.10 on OSX, I get: `Compile error:
Method or data member not found`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this brilliant solution. If I want the US English, can I just change `msoLanguageIDEnglishUK` to `msoLanguageIDEnglishUS`?

Comment: one other issue I just saw is that it apparently doesn't change the language of the text inside tables.

Comment: For those new to Macros (on PowerPoint), help yourself: https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/online-marketing/online-sales/creating-a-powerpoint-macro/

Comment: Got "Execution error" on line targetShape.TextFrame.TextRange.languageID = languageID with Office 365.

Answer (score 29):

The existing answers work for text that is present in the outline. Unfortunately in my case this didn't cover a significant part of the text, including figures, tables, etc.

This macro solved the problem for me :

```vba
 Sub ChangeProofingLanguageToEnglish()
    Dim j, k, m, scount, fcount, gcount As Integer
    scount = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    For j = 1 To scount
        fcount = ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes.Count
        For k = 1 To fcount
            If ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes(k).HasTextFrame Then
                ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes(k) _
                .TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = msoLanguageIDEnglishUS
            End If
            If ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes(k).Type = msoGroup Then
                gcount = ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes(k).GroupItems.Count
                For m = 1 To gcount
                    If ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes(k).GroupItems.Item(m).HasTextFrame Then
                    ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes(k).GroupItems.Item(m) _
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = msoLanguageIDEnglishUS
            End If
                Next m
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
End Sub
```

The "msoLanguageIDEnglishUS" which is used in the above macro can be replaced by any desired language. The full list of languages can be found in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432635.aspx)

(Credit goes to Ganesh Kumar who posted the original macro [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-powerpoint/setting-language-for-entire-presentation-all-at/4f8ab731-9fcf-4b64-9433-2bac1b51eff3). I added support for first level of shape grouping. To further improve it the macro can be made recursive to look for groups which contain other groups, etc.)

Comment: +1 Good start. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/680281/200425) for a fully recursive version based on this answer.

Answer (score 18):

Based on Inigo, Duncan, Maria and DomDev's answers, this works for shapes, tables, groups, SmartArt, now and in the future:

```vb
Sub ChangeProofingLanguageToFrench()
    Dim j, k As Integer
    Dim languageID As MsoLanguageID

    'Set this to your preferred language
    languageID = msoLanguageIDFrench

    'Loop all the slides in the document, and change the language
    For j = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        For k = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes.Count
            ChangeAllSubShapes ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes(k), languageID
        Next k
    Next j

    'Loop all the master slides, and change the language
    For j = 1 To ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Count
        For k = 1 To ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(j).Shapes.Count
            ChangeAllSubShapes ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(j).Shapes(k), languageID
        Next k
    Next j

    'Change the default presentation language, so that all new slides respect the new language
    ActivePresentation.DefaultLanguageID = languageID
End Sub

Sub ChangeAllSubShapes(targetShape As Shape, languageID As MsoLanguageID)
    Dim i As Integer, r As Integer, c As Integer

    If targetShape.HasTextFrame Then
        targetShape.TextFrame.TextRange.languageID = languageID
    End If

    If targetShape.HasTable Then
        For r = 1 To targetShape.Table.Rows.Count
            For c = 1 To targetShape.Table.Columns.Count
                targetShape.Table.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.languageID = languageID
            Next
        Next
    End If

    Select Case targetShape.Type
        Case msoGroup, msoSmartArt
            For i = 1 To targetShape.GroupItems.Count
                ChangeAllSubShapes targetShape.GroupItems.Item(i), languageID
            Next i
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: As for other solutions, on when running this in PowerPoint 16.10 on OSX, I get: `Compile error:
Method or data member not found`. Any suggested solutions? It seems to highlight `.DefaultLanguageID`.

Comment: @EtienneLow-Décarie: The API might have changed in PowerPoint 16; I don't have it so I can't check, sorry.

Comment: Works for me in Powerpoint 2016 on Windows 7 (exact MS Office version is 16.0.11029.20108)

Comment: Perfect! Only improvement I could think of is changing the language for slide notes sections, too :)

Comment: The compile error above is because the LanguageID property was not included in the TextFrame object in later PowerPoint versions. Use TextFrame2 instead of TextFrame...

Comment: Got "Execution error" on line targetShape.TextFrame.TextRange.languageID = languageID with PowerPoint 365. It turns out it was an older file from an older PPT version. I had to copy paste everything in a new PPT file, and it worked. Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Also, this does not change the Mask language. Any way to include it too?

Answer (score 10):

In addition to answer provided by [Mastergalen](https://superuser.com/a/567351/348544) and to address comments regarding newly type text:

If you will notice, that language will automatically change back whenever you start to type new text (which is very annoying), you have to change current default language for PowerPoint:

- make sure PowerPoint window is an active window
- in the `Windows Taskbar` (yes, actually not in PowerPoint), check if `Language bar` is visible,

  - if not go to `Control Panel > Region and Language > Keyboards and Languages`. Click `Change keybords...`, switch to `Language bar` tab and check `Docked in the taskbar` option. (this is from Win7, so might be a bit different in other versions).
- now key action - in the `Language bar` in the taskbar, **click language code and switch to EN** (if you want currently to use English in PowerPoint). From now on, all new text in PowerPoint will be in the selected language :-)
- if you want write in your original language, just change it back.

Comment: But that also changes the keyboard layout, doesn't it?... I want to type English text but I really want to keep my German keyboard layout....

Comment: @JohannesS. If you right click `En` in the task bar and select `Settings..` you will see in Installed languages German (DE) and English (En), if you expand English, there will be `Keyboards` listed, expand Keyboards, and add your prefered German keyboard, probably remove English one also. I didnt try it, but should work in theory ;-)

Comment: Wait, so I need to change my keyboard language if I want to have different proofing language? That's stupid.

Comment: This is THE answer. I changed the preferred language to English with Hungarian keyboard. Nothing else worked well. If you don't do something like this then all your new English text will be all underlined even if you type in a text box that you previously select all-d to English. It's crazy.

Comment: If you find that this still doesn't work, create a new text box. Then change the language to another language, and then back to the one you desire. This worked for me. I had ENG (English) selected, but it was still creating text boxes in ES (Spanish). Then I changed to ES again, typed some text, and then changed back to ENG. Only now were the new text boxes in the desired language. Simply changing back and forth between languages might do the trick if it's still not working as specified here.

Comment: @MatějRačinský no, you need to change the input language, not your keyboard layout. Windows is smart enough to distinguish between the two, so you can enter Spanish text with a French keyboard layout, and PowerPoint will check Spanish spelling. That is actually quite smart. To configure, in Windows 10 21H1, go to Language settings. You configure a list of Preferred languages at the bottom, and for each one, you can choose a (potentially different) keyboard layout. The language bar then allows you to switch between languages as well as betwen layouts independently.

Answer (score 8):

The version of Duncan works well for everything but tables.
I found another code which seems to also work with tables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735765/powerpoint-2007-set-language-on-tables-charts-etc-that-contains-text

```vb
Public Sub changeLanguage()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim gi As GroupShapes '<-this was added. used below
    lang = "English"
    'lang = "Norwegian"
    'Determine language selected
    If lang = "English" Then
        lang = msoLanguageIDEnglishUK
    ElseIf lang = "Norwegian" Then
        lang = msoLanguageIDNorwegianBokmol
    End If
    'Set default language in application
    ActivePresentation.DefaultLanguageID = lang

    'Set language in each textbox in each slide
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Dim oShape As Shape
        For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
            'Check first if it is a table
            If oShape.HasTable Then
                For r = 1 To oShape.Table.Rows.Count
                    For c = 1 To oShape.Table.Columns.Count
                    oShape.Table.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.languageID = lang
                    Next
                Next
            Else
                Set gi = oShape.GroupItems
                'Check if it is a group of shapes
                If Not gi Is Nothing Then
                    If oShape.GroupItems.Count > 0 Then
                        For i = 0 To oShape.GroupItems.Count - 1
                            oShape.GroupItems(i).TextFrame.TextRange.languageID = lang
                        Next
                    End If
                'it's none of the above, it's just a simple shape, change the language ID
                Else
                    oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.languageID = lang
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to have worked on Office 365

Comment: Powerpoint is around since 1990, and one has to mess with flippin' VB to change the language for the entire presentation. Somewhat pathetic. Nevertheless, thanks for the script. It seems to have worked on my Powerpoint for Microsoft365 (Version 2304 Build 16.0.something.something)

Answer (score 6):

I made an add-in back in 2014 for myself which still works fine in PowerPoint 2016. https://github.com/wobba/officeaddin/releases/tag/v1.0.1

It scans for used languages, and allows you to change all at once, looping over.

[image]

Comment: really - this didn't make it into Powerpoint itself and is only available for windows?

Comment: I know.. and the add-in model using javascript don't support iterating over object setting the language :(

Comment: Does not appear in Office 365, sadly

Comment: The add-in still works fine in Windows desktop version of PowerPoint. But not for Online web version as the API does not support setting language.

Answer (score 0):

If other methods don't help, unexpected changes of the language may also be caused by the language setting in the slide master.

In order to change it, go to *View > Slide Master*, select the parent-most master slide, select all elements, and change the language as described in the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/567351/191663). The change should propagate to all layouts, though placeholder text will remain in the original language.

If possible, the clean solution is to use a template configured with the correct language. However, depending on company-mandated templates / the office installation, or simply when trying to fix an existing file, this might not be possible.

Comment: It doesn't work on 365  v2008 build 13127.21064. Powerpoint always detect languages even if they are not in the list of language preferences. At the moment i have to go to every text box, select all, and set the "proofing language" to the desired and default. Powerpoint is a really unprofessional software

Comment: If only it was as simple as that :)