# How to globally change the language in PowerPoint Slide Masters

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, language, master

There are a lot of answers about how to change the language by going into the outline view, marking everything and changing the language. But that's no use if the languages in the Master Slides have not been changed. 
How can I change the languages in the Master Slides, without picking one frame after the other and doing it manually?

Comment: You pretty much need to do it one text box at a time (and that still leaves other bits untouched).  If you're good with VBA, the job can be automated.  Or there are commercial PowerPoint add-ins that do the job for you.  I have one at PPTools.com and there's another at PPTAlchemy.co.uk

Comment: As Steve said no other options apart from VBA/add-ins. We also started to offer this very helpful button to set the proofing language in our add-in: www.veodin.com/slideproof

Comment: You can try code [here](http://superuser.com/a/1119420/245595), or the free add-in linked [here](http://superuser.com/a/547086/245595).

Comment: The stupidity of Power Point is beyond imagination. Try to use the [solution with changing Windows language](https://superuser.com/a/1096722/156554). Worked for me as a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Click icon at the bottom to be in "Normal" viewing mode. On the left panel, click the "Outline" tab, select all, under Review->Language->Set Proofing Language set desire language.

Comment: This answer clearly contradicts OP's intention. It is clearly said in the question that solution using outline view is **not** what OP's asking for.