# Change powerpoint spell language in a fast way

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, language, spell-check

not sure this is the right place but I found a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/55034/change-the-spell-checking-language-on-a-powerpoint-presentation), so probably it is.

I'm working on some presentations which contain text in two different languages. These languages are interleaved in the same text-box. These is because I'm talking Italian but I have to use some English terms.

Is there a way for changing in a fast way the language of a single word?

Currently I'm doing the following:

1. select the word
2. Tools -> Language...
3. select the language
4. confirm

This can be really long when in the same slide I have several words in English.

Event better would be having a spell checker that automatically understands the language.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can install another language in the Windows itself, after that you will have a floating bar and by just clicking on it you will be able to switch languages.

To install another language and keyboard layout in Windows XP, follow these steps:

1. In the Windows XP standard Start menu, click **Start**, and then click **Control Panel**.
2. In the Windows XP classic Start menu, click **Start**, click **Settings**, and then click **Control Panel**.
3. Double-click **Regional and Language Options**.
4. Click the Languages tab, and then click Details under "Text Services and Input Languages".
5. Click **Add** under "Installed Services", and then click the language you want to add and the keyboard layout you want to use for that language.
6. To configure the settings for the Language bar, click **Language Bar** under "Preferences".

You can use it with the following key-commands:
`alt+shift` : Switch IME modes (between "EN" and "JP" mode, for example)
[image: See here screenshot of the language bar]

**Note:**
These instructions should also work with Windows 7.

**Links:**

- [Add or change an input language](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Add-or-change-an-input-language) official instructions from MS.
- [Switch between different languages as you type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/switch-between-different-languages-as-you-type-HA010244790.aspx)

Comment: They actually don't work in Windows 7 because the language packs were not in every version of Windows 7.

Comment: Language packs were made available later for some editions as updates.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972813
from question its known that the lang is available.

Comment: @Lamb I didn't specified that but I'm not under windows. However it seems that this will change the language of the entire slide, not just a word. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @lucaghera Question was tagged MS-powerpoint so I assumed that its windows. No, it will not change the language of whole slide, instead it will provide you ability to switch b/w typing lang easily.

Comment: see the edited answer.